# Git command alias pipe for powershell

Tags: git, powershell

I want to create an alias in git `git cleanIgnore` but I can not figure out how to pipe the output from command 1 to command 2.

I'm using PowerShell and the following command works great from the prompt

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | %{git rm --cached $_}
```

and I defined this in my global config like this, it doesn't work

```
[alias]
    cleanIgnore = "!git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | %{git rm --cached $_}"
    cleanIgnore2= "!git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore "
```

I can get the first half to work as an alias, but I keep getting an error on usage when i do `git cleanIgnore`

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | %{git rm --cached $_}: %{git: command not found
fatal: While expanding alias 'cleanignore': 'git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | %{git rm --cached $_}': No such file or directory
```

It seems that the `!` isn't just passing everything to the shell to execute, but is doing something more still

**update/answer**

```
[alias] 
    cleanIgnore = "!powershell.exe -command 'git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | %{git rm --cached $_}'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another way to create a "new" git command is :

- create a script named `git-cleanIgnore` (a powershell script in your case)
- put this script on your path

---

regarding the `!` alias : I guess git does not execute the command using powershell

you may try to use commmands like `xargs` (or other linux standard tools, which you could for example install on windows using Cygwin),
or see if you can call something like `powershell.exe -command '%{git rm --cached $_}'` in your alias

(read the documentation of powershell to see how you can pass a command as an argument to `powershell.exe`)

---

[edit] : you found out the way to have your command executed by powershell :

```
[alias]
    cleanIgnore = "!powershell.exe -command 'git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | %{git rm --cached $_}'"
```

Comment: awesome!  if you want to update your reponse with this

    [alias]
        cleanIgnore = "!powershell.exe -command 'git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | %{git rm --cached $_}'"

ill mark this as the accepted answer